# Making the design more uniform?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Website design with Bootstrap and I just made this simple start here which looks alright but needs some adjustment to be more uniform and pretty.

[image]

As you can see here the Jumbotron I've used seems fairly centered but the Well and Search Bar underneath it does not. I would like some help so that I can make it fit better together :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="jumbotron" style="width: 100%">
                        <h1>Cool Text</h1>
                        <p>Catchphrase</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-bar-container">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try enclosing search-bar-container inside a div with Class of Container

Comment: All space as in horizontal or vertical?

Comment: Horizontal spaces :)

Comment: you might want to ask another question for this to get faster response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `class="navbar-form"` which is meant for use inside a navbar, that's why it won't occupy 100% of the div it's in.

Depending on if you doing anything else inside these container, you currently don't need to use any columns or rows. I've also add some padding to your jumbotron for under 768px becauseyou'' see the text float up to the edge of the div otherwise.

See example Snippet.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .jumbotron.jumbotronic {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="well well-sm">
  <h3>Without Col/Row</h3>

</div>
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotronic">
      <h1>Cool Text</h1>

      <p>Catchphrase</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search-bar-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="well">
      <form role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="well well-sm">
  <h3>With Col/Row</h3>

</div>
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotronic">
          <h1>Cool Text</h1>

          <p>Catchphrase</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search-bar-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="well">
          <form role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for both a great explanation and the examples. I would not have figured that one out on my own that's for sure :)

Comment: No problem and glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, container has some predefined width and margin:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="jumbotron" style="width: 100%">
                    <h1>Cool Text</h1>
                    <p>Catchphrase</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="search-bar-container">
        <div class="well">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That takes care of the well at least. Now I just need the search bar to take up all available space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container .jumbotron, .container-fluid .jumbotron {
    padding-right: 19px;
    padding-left: 19px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container header-container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Cool Text</h1>
    <p>Catchphrase</p>
  </div>

  <form class="search-bar-container well" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </div>
   </div>
  </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay I tried that but the Search Bar still doesn't use up all available width space in the Well http://puu.sh/l1W7U/aeba748140.png

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the answer you accepted.